# Why didn't the humans in the Animatrix take out the Machines earlier?

Tags: the-matrix, the-animatrix

In the Animatrix, we see that the humans end up bombing 01 - the Machine City.

Why wouldn't they just make a direct assault on the Machine City with troops, tanks, etc etc? This would have been far more effective I think, or they could have used some sort of EMP bomb instead of nukes (I'm aware that nuclear weapons do have an initial EMP upon detonation).

The Animatrix sort of depicts mankind to be morons....I mean, as a species we are, but we're not as dumb as it makes us out to be. You look at human history and when our backs are against the wall, we're capable of doing some pretty incredible things.

Comment: Why would you send in tanks and troops when you have nukes?

Comment: Given that *The One* is a design feature, maybe *The Animatrix* stories are as well, maybe they are machine made and that is why the humans are depicted as morons.

Comment: It was full fledged war. You are simply underestimating machines.

Answer (score 16):

You seem to be dramatically underestimating the resilience and intelligence of the machines.

### We nuked 'em and we nuked 'em good

> *The prolonged barrage engulfed Zero One in the glow of a thousand
>   suns. But unlike their former masters with their delicate flesh, the
>   machines had little to fear of the bombs' radiation and heat.*

Prolonged. Barrage. We hit them **over and over again**. And when they didn't die, we hit them again. Unfortunately, all it takes is a bit of [hardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening) and an EMP will have little effect.

### We attacked, but they attacked more

> *Thus did Zero One's troops advance outwards in every direction. And
>   one after another, mankind surrendered its territories.*

Note that this was a war of *attrition*. The machines factories were clearly capable of creating robots at a faster rate than we were able to destroy them and their soldiers were able to kill us faster than we can reproduce. The result was inevitable.

### Backs against the wall, we innovated.

> *So the leaders of men conceived of their most desperate strategy yet.
>   A final solution - the destruction of the sky.*

[Operation Dark Storm](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Operation_Dark_Storm) was an act of genius. Without power, the machines should have been screwed. Unfortunately, they innovated right back, developing fusion and using humans as a power source. They out-fought us, and ultimately they out-thought us too. **Poor us.**

Comment: And yet we still drone on with our AI research nowadays lol. The Matrix, Terminator, these movies are examples of why AI is a very bad idea :P.

Comment: @RyanJ - I have long been a proponent of the Skynet Doctrine of Science Research. All scientific research should be graded 1-10 with 1 being "no possibility of helping to create a malevolent AI" and 10 being "intentionally developing a malevolent AI". Anything that scores a 5 or more should be banned.

Comment: @Richard I think we should wait at least a century or two before pursuing AI, hopefully by then we're a more peaceful species and could find a way to exist with AI beings instead of trying to destroy them. Ex. Star Trek Next Generation, everyone co-exists with Data aboard the Enterprise.

Comment: @RyanJ and yet there are is the opposing fiction depicting at worst ambivalent AI, such as Bicentennial Man and Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: @RyanJ: You do realize that are you referencing completely fictional movies imagined by a few individuals as real-life reasons to not do something, right?

Comment: What constraints to AI and machine learning algorithms are needed to prevent AI from becoming a dystopian threat to humanity?

https://www.quora.com/What-constraints-to-AI-and-machine-learning-algorithms-are-needed-to-prevent-AI-from-becoming-a-dystopian-threat-to-humanity/answer/Thaddeus-Howze

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - The main problem is that while we may all agree that developing a malevolent AI is a *bad thing*, that doesn't stop scientists from doing it. Only strong legislation will do that.

Comment: As a physicist who has done some consulting for people working in AI, I feel I ought to point out that intelligence and self-awareness are very different things.

Comment: @Richard Unless they're entirely funded by the government, I don't see that working.

Comment: @Axelrod - Hence **strong** legislation, in the same way that we've (largely) prevented the human cloning genie from coming out of the bottle by making it impossible for the few rogue scientists who might consider it from accessing world class laboratories in the Western world.

Comment: The issue with strong legislation and prohibition is that it is, in the long term, a completely ineffective solution to the problem. For instance, even if AI R&D is banned or strongly controlled in the west, there is nothing to stop Russia or China from aggressively pursuing the technology and quickly catching up with and surpassing our tech. AI represents a very similar type of situation to that which arose with nuclear technology, and the same type of game theory analysis needs to be applied to our decision making process.

Comment: @user251563 - There's a good reason why Russia and China aren't aggressively pursuing human cloning tech and that's because legislation can be trans-national when it benefit everyone.

Comment: That's true, however there will always be individuals, nations, and other organizations who operate outside of - or even opposed to - the international framework. A good example of this is North Korea, but allow me to provide a better one. The chemistry and logistics involved in the synthesis and distribution of drugs like LSD were at one time factors that entirely precluded their production outside of governments or regulated corporations. As information is democratized via the Internet and the barrier to entry diminishes, the production and use of illicit tech will become more feasible.

Comment: @user251563 - Yes indeed. But look at the problems that the Norks are having developing even simple nuclear weapons without access to extra-national resources like conferences, facilities, training and education. It's bled their military dry and the end result is a nuclear bomb roughly on a par with the ones that the US had nearly 75 years ago and no reliable delivery system. This is the system working well.

Comment: From what I know it is very much a genie in the bottle situation - once it's out it isn't going back in. I do fundamentally agree that strong legislation could possibly prevent the development of true, autonomous AI, but in practice I believe that it's going to come whether it is regulated or not. As another hypothetical: perhaps international legislation could have prevented atomic weapons being built if such laws were in place before WWII started - but would the US have held back if the war went differently and the Axis powers were poised to win - just to uphold the law?

Comment: @Richard that's another good point, and I certainly don't contest that the tech will not lag badly without the strong, open support of the international community. The interesting thing with AI though is that it seems a bit like the atom bomb in another way: it might only take the implementation of one actual example to change the world.

Comment: @Praxis bingo!!! I fully agree!! I personally know an AI research engineer. She specifically told me the firm she works for knows the “intelligence” part is actually easy. It’s creating a self-aware, sentient AI mind like that which Hollywood and SF writers imagine, that’s been a brick wall to engineers all this time. They can’t figure out how THAT aspect of the mind works.

Answer (score -1):

Humanity celebrated the advent of artificial intelligence and the industrial prosperity a neigh limitless workforce of unpaid workers brought. In a few years the machines would have dominated manufacturing on a global scale, effective seizing control of humanity's industrial infrastructure. By the time the machines *started* requesting political representation at the United Nations (or whatever that summit was) humanity could hardly refuse.

They refused anyway.

An industrially crippled and politically divided humanity went to war with a well supplied, **heavily entrenched**, technologically superior, inherently more durable robot army that had practically limitless reinforcements. The only advantage humanity had was initially the number of troops, but biological, chemical and radioactive weaponry would have soon changed that.